# window.onerror and [object Event]

Tags: javascript

I have some errorlogging code on my website that saves Javascript errors to a file so later i can look to se if there is problems with my code in some browsers.

Sometimes i get a error message like **message:[object Event] url:undefined line:undefined** so i dont know where the error accures.

How do i get more info from **message** when it is [object Event] so i can know what file and line number the error is from.

```
window.onerror = error;

function error(message, url, line) {

   // sometimes message is [object Event]

}
```

I am thinks something like this.

```
window.onerror = error;

function error(message, url, line) {

   // sometimes message is [object Event]


    if (typeof message === 'object') {

        message = message
            + ' + '
            + message.url
            + ' + '
            + message.lineno;

    }

}
```

Trying this but i get **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'serialize'**

```
if (typeof message === 'object') {

   message = JSON.serialize(message);

}
```

With JSON.stringify(message) i get **Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**

```
if (typeof message === 'object') {

   message = JSON.stringify(message);

}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm having the same issues.

Comment: @DirkBoer Did you figure out how to deal with this issue?

Comment: I had the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60937599/694195

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you get something like `[someting Something]` in JS, it usually means that it is an object. You can do a `console.log(message)` and inspect the contents of the object. It would look like

```
{
  somethingHere : 'data',
  anotherHere : 'more data'
}
```

To access them, you can do it in the dot notation:

```
theObject.somethingHere //data
```

In your case, that would be like this, where `something` is a key from the object.

```
message.something
```

Comment: Thanks but the error comes from when other people access my website with whatever browser/program they are using so i cant open the console.

Comment: @scootergrisen I think you should serialize the message into a string instead, like `message = JSON.serialize(message)`. That way, you get the error object as a string.

Comment: Ok i'm waiting for the same error to come again so i can se the result.

Comment: I'm getting a error when using serialize. Se above.

Comment: Did you mean **JSON.stringify()** ?

Comment: With **JSON.stringify(message)** i get **Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**

Comment: @scootergrisen Yah, that's the one. Have mixed up my code.

Comment: Do you know how come it says **Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON** ?

Comment: @scootergrisen The `message` is self-referencing. There's a property that points back to the object itself.

Comment: @scootergrisen You can read more about [the Error object here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

Answer (score 0):

On which browser or browsers are you seeing this `[Event object]` message occurring? One possible way to inspect the contents of the object is:

```
var messageString = '';
for (var x in message) {
  if (messageString) messageString += ', ';
  messageString += x + ': ' + message[x];
}
message = '{' + messageString + '}';
```

If you can give any kind of reproducible test case for this onerror message, including browser versions on which is happens, that would help a lot.