# Difficult to diagnose circular JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have an error in my error handler :) `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

I suspect that there is another exception thrown inside the `JSON.stringify` call and that is what is causing it? I certainly can't see how `err_msg`, `err_url`, or `err_line` could refer to themselves somehow.

Is there a way I can protect this code from becoming circular? Does anyone have some insight into exactly why this error is arising?

```
window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(err_msg, err_url, err_line) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "/log-receiver", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Csrftoken', document.getElementsByName("csrfmiddlewaretoken")[0].value);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        message: err_msg,
        url: err_url,
        line: err_line,
        level: 'ERROR'
    }));

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you `console.log` the object and just go through it with the console explorer? I think it'll help you.

Comment: `err_msg` is not a string, it's an object that has recursive references.

Comment: @Aplet123 no I can't reproduce it locally. I see it in logs only.

Comment: @Barmar are you sure about that? Do you have a reference?

Comment: It's the only thing that explains the error message.

Comment: But the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror says it should be a string. What does `console.log(err_msg)` show?

Comment: When I force an error locally it's definitely a string. Every now and then in production I get that error. This error handler sends errors to my backend for logging (that's why it's ancient js - it's *supposed* to be bullet proof).

Comment: @jsj Does your error logging server record the browser that the people used? Are they all using old browsers?

Comment: @Aplet123  pretty sure this was one of them `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; en-gb; GT-N8010 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30` (one of the ones that experienced this issue)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters this. It turned out that very occasionally a browser was sending an `ErrorEvent` object as the argument to `window.onerror`. A added a check to my error handler to deal with this case.